# Easiest way to create a javascript date from "18th apr 2011" / "1st jun 1980" format

Tags: javascript

This works:

```
var myDateString = '19th sep 2015';
myDateString = myDateString.replace('st','');
myDateString = myDateString.replace('th','');
myDateString = myDateString.replace('nd','');
myDateString = myDateString.replace('rd','');
var date = new Date(myDateString);
```

But is there a cleaner way?  Can I pass the date format (including the ordinal part) to the Date constuctor?

Comment: `'19th sep 2015'.replace(/(\d+)\w{2}(.+)/, '$1$2')`

Comment: Yours is the answer that I've decided to use @Tushar, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't rely on it parsing correctly for all people - for instance, people in France might have their locale set to French (surprise) and that would fail to parse `apr` for instance, because for them it's `avr`.

Instead, parse it yourself:

```
var myDateString = '19th sep 2015';
var parts = myDateString.split(" ");
var date = parts[0].replace(/\D/g,''); // keep only numbers
var month = "janfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec".indexOf(parts[1].toLowerCase())/3;
var year = parts[2];

var date = new Date(year, month, date);
// note because of how we got the month, it's already conveniently zero-based
```

Comment: Good point on the locale.  Maybe I should be passing an ISO format alongside my custom format in the PHP, e.g. in a data-attribute on the relevant tag.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to use a library like `moment.js` or the date part of `sugar.js`.
To do this properly by hand is not fun.

**Update**

If you're in full control of the dates, just use ISO 8601 date format, which the constructor of `Date` understands in any browser.

Comment: Using either of those adds a lot more complexity than my simple JS string replace code.  Can you explain why a library would be better?

Bear in mind I'm in full control of the dates I'm parsing, they're output via my server side PHP code.  I don't have to worry about user-generated input.

Answer (score -1):

Use Moment.js library and use your date string like this:

```
moment('19th sep 2015', 'Do MMMM YYYY').format("D MMMM YYYY")
```

Output:

"19 September 2015"